Is there a way to hide the flashing text cursor without disabling user-select?
Is there a way to hide the flashing text cursor without disabling user-select?
When an element with text is clicked, most browsers display a flashing cursor indicating where the selection point is.
This can be disabled by setting user-select to none, however I don't want to this. I want the text to be selectable, but I do not want a flashing cursor to display after the user clicks on a button or a piece of text.
Example Page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Women%27s_Championship
Click any text within the page and a flashing selection cursor appears.
Screen Capture of Behavior
https://imgflip.com/gif/8wysm7

caret-color: transparent see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color is that what you want or do you want to see it but not blinking?

That's what I was looking to do.  If you want to write up an answer I will accept it.

That behavior doesn't happen on my browser. It would happen if you turn Caret Navigation (or Caret Browsing) on, though.

If you don't want to enable caret browsing, In Chrome disable caret Browsing by, going to settings > accessibility > Navigate pages with a text cursor. Or pressing f7

As you want to make the caret invisible, rather than solid, you can use
caret-color: transparent;

see developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color
I’m afraid I can’t put a runnable snippet up as I’m confined to a touch device, but caniuse reports good support across the major browsers.
